# kdb q: find the C libraries it loads

Tags: kdb, k

I have this line of code:

```
loadedFunc: `:mylib 2:(`myfunc;1)
```

so from the [kdb/q reference.](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#2-c-shared-objects), it means loading "my func", which has one argument from the dynamic library with name mylib .

Where is the path can I locate this physical library of mylib? I don't see any path specified elsewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path is set as mentioned [here](http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/using-c-functions/)

It will attempt to load from the current working directory (as `\pwd` ) first.

If it doesn't find the appropriate library there, then it will attempt to load from the `$QHOME/[installationType]` directory (so C:/q/w32 by default for Windows 32bit, etc.)